# Split array into two based on complex criteria.

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
a =  [[4, 5, 59708], [6, 5, 93676], [8, 9, 3800], [8, 12, 3200], [8, 15, 6400], [8, 18, 400], [8, 20, 3200], [8, 21, 1838], [10, 11, 200], [10, 16, 100], [10, 17, 3200], [10, 19, 1400], [13, 14, 7344]]
```

Now I need to split this array into two arrays (top_3 and rest).

The top 3 should contain the top 3 entries for each index 0. The ranking should be based on index 2.

```
top_3 =  [
  [6, 5, 93676], # (93676) Only one entry for index(0) == 6
  [4, 5, 59708],
  [8, 15, 6400], # (6400, 3800, 3200) top 3 for index(0) == 8
  [8, 9, 3800],  #
  [8, 20, 3200], # 
  [10, 11, 200],
  [10, 17, 3200],
  [10, 19, 1400], 
  [13, 14, 7344]]
```

The rest of the values not in the top 3 should be stored in another array:

```
rest = [[8, 18, 400], [8, 12, 3200], [8, 21, 1838], [10, 11, 200], [10, 16, 100]]
```

Comment: Cool. Let us know when you're done.

Comment: Haha, Sergio is somewhat right, please provide more exact data on what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: You should create uobject so it is easier to know what data you are storing. Look into Struct for example.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot have permission to post my code to generate the first a array, but what would be the best algorithm to generate the final lower array? I trying to use a.sort_by {|e| [[e[2]]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really hard to follow, but I would try something like:

```
top3 = a.group_by(&:first).map{|a,b| b.sort_by(&:last).last(3)}.flatten(1)

lower = a - top3
```